# Format of Teams Chat URL

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

I have an app that runs within Teams that shows a list of employees, name, email, presence, title and phone.

For the name column I would like to present it as a link that when clicked will open up a chat within the Teams desktop or mobile app with that employee. If there is an existing chat session, it should go to that, else create a new chat. It should not open the web client and go through the hassle of choosing to then open in the desktop app.

I was previously using this format:

[https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=user@user.com](https://MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=user@user.com)

This caused the whole web client flow, so after some digging around I changed it to:

[MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=user@user.com](https://MSTeams:/l/chat/0/0?users=user@user.com)

This seems to work for an existing chat but does not work for a new chat. The To: field at the top of the page is not completed.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Mar

Comment: It should work with this format: https://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=<user1>,<user2>,...&topicName=<chat name>&message=<precanned text>

Reference doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generate-a-deep-link-to-a-chat

Can you please share the error log or screenshot for your issue?

Comment: While testing the format I found a formatting issue in my string concatenation that caused the users= parameter to be inserted 2x. Once I corrected that it actually starts a new chat if there is no previous chat session, and opens a previous chat if there was one in the chat history.

It does still invoke the browser, forcing the user to acknowledge opening the Teams link, but that is user dependent so I cant get around that. I was hoping there is some sort of internal link structure I can use, since my app is running inside the Teams client. Is that not possible?

Comment: You need to call this deeplink through inside teams or directly through browser.so you do not get any pop up to acknowledge opening the Teams link.

Comment: Well the link works but the browser always seems to popup for confirmation.

I have a video of the issue but cant post it here due to PII content. I have no idea how to mask that out across a whole video